# Marble Algorithms Using Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

During a job interview for a computer science job you are hypothetically given two identical marbles and then asked to figure out the following problem.  Find an algorithm which minimizes the maximum number of steps needed to find the smallest floor j so that a marble breaks when dropped from floor j but not from floor j-1 in a skyscraper with 100 floors.

I think this problem has to do something with induction. I'm not sure how to start with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do You guys have a Idea of how to do this? Our teacher said it relates to discrete math. I would appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with binary search. That approach will not work here, but the ideas are similiar.

Comment: Can you show me the idea behind this please?

Comment: procedure binary search (x: integer, a1,a2,...,an: increasing integers) i := 1{i is left endpoint of search interval} j := n{j is right endpoint of search interval} while i<j m :=(i +j)/2 if x>a m then i := m+1 else j := m if x = ai then location:= i else location:=0 return location{location is the subscript i of the term ai equal to x, or 0 if x is not found}

Comment: Can I ask what your best algorithm so far is?

Comment: here join this room. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14304/marble-algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy will look like this: We try the first marble from floors $n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots$ until it breaks from floor $n_k$ say. After that the only valid strategy is to try $n_{k-1}+1,n_{k-1}+2,\ldots, n_k-1$ (with $n_0=0$ understood) until the second marble breaks (or we have reached the end of the list).
So the worst case number of tries if the first marble breaks at $n_k$ is $k+n_k-n_{k-1}$. If the overall worst case number is $m$, this implies $n_k\le n_{k-1}+m-k$, i.e. $n_1\le m$, $n_2\le 2m-1$, $n_3\le 3m-3$, etc. By induction, $n_k\le km-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$. The maximum of the right hand side is reached at $k=m-1$ (or $k=m$) where $n_{m-1}=n_m=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$. With $m=13$ we achieve at most $n_m=91$ and have no more tries left to distibuish between $92, 93, \ldots 100$. With $m=14$ we have $n_m=105$, which is enough to cover the 100-storey building.
Thus our sequence $n_k$ is $14,27,39,50,60,69,77,84,90,95,99$ and if the first marble survives the 99th floor, we can try the 100th floor immediately and find the answer in 12 tries. But if the first "bad" floor is among the $n_k$, we do need 14 tries.